# Get Object from array of objects if condition is met

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a 'very big object' which come from external api. I want get the ids of object base by the value supplied by the user, in this case, the id of category' Here is the simplified content of an object containing two

```
 { 
  "6":{  
  "id":2045,
  "categories":[  
     {  
        "id":7,
        "name":"Day Trips & Excursions Outside the City"
     },
     {  
        "id":34,
        "name":"Day-Tour"
     },
     {  
        "id":8,
        "name":"Food, Wine & Gastronomy"
     }
   ],
  },
 "8":{  
  "id":20456,
  "categories":[  
     {  
        "id":17,
        "name":"Day Trips & Excursions Outside the City"
     },
     {  
        "id":2,
        "name":"Day-Tour"
     },
     {  
        "id":8,
        "name":"Food, Wine & Gastronomy"
     }
  ],
 },
},
```

In this example, i want to get the ids of object, example id: 2045 if one of categories id matches the id supplied by the user. So for example a user supplies 8, it should return id both id 20145 and 20456, if a user supplied 17, it should return the id of 20456.

I tried

```
   const acti = activitiesbigobjct.filter((e) => e.categories);
```

But I got error filter is not a function error

I tried something like

```
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(activitiesbigobj)) {
          console.log(value)
     }
```

But I think its not the best solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the values, simply use `Object.values`:

```
Object.values(activitiesbigobjct).filter((e) => e.categories.some(id => id === 8)).map(e => e.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `Array.forEach()`

```js
var obj = { "6": { id: 2045, categories: [{ id: 7, name: "Day Trips & Excursions Outside the City" }, { id: 34, name: "Day-Tour" }, { id: 8, name: "Food, Wine & Gastronomy" }] }, "8": { id: 20456, categories: [{ id: 17, name: "Day Trips & Excursions Outside the City" }, { id: 2, name: "Day-Tour" }, { id: 8, name: "Food, Wine & Gastronomy" }] }};

var userId = 8;
var result = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
  obj[key].categories.forEach((category)=>{
    if(category.id === userId)
        result.push(obj[key].id);
  });

});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filtzer the object's values and map the `id`.

```js
function getId(subId) {
    return Object
        .values(data)
        .filter(({ categories }) => categories.some(({ id }) => id === subId))
        .map(({ id }) => id)
}

var data = { "6": { id: 2045, categories: [{ id: 7, name: "Day Trips & Excursions Outside the City" }, { id: 34, name: "Day-Tour" }, { id: 8, name: "Food, Wine & Gastronomy" }] }, "8": { id: 20456, categories: [{ id: 17, name: "Day Trips & Excursions Outside the City" }, { id: 2, name: "Day-Tour" }, { id: 8, name: "Food, Wine & Gastronomy" }] } };;

console.log(getId(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is happening because `.filter()` is an function on an array and your big object is just that, an object.

You could put the big object into an array and then use `.filter().map()` to first filter and then get the values you want.

A simple example:

```
[{ id: 1, name: "a"},{ id: 2, name: "b" }].filter(x => x.id === 2).map(x => x.name)
```

Which will return `"b"` the `name` property from the filtered results.

You would need to do things a little differently as you want the `id` of the parent if the child `category` matches, so something like:

```
[<your data>].filter(x => x.categories.id === <your id (17)>).map(x => x.id)
```